# using PostgreSQL for storage image routes

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, postgresql, select

I have a database in postgresql where I save a serial number and a string. I use that to storage a image location on my disk.

id_image ------ route

"1"; ----------- "./img/one.jpg"

"2"; ----------- "./img/two.png"

"3"; ----------- "./img/wheels.jpg"

"4"; ----------- "./img/core.jpg"

"6"; ----------- "./img/idcol.jpg"

I've got a function in jquery that reads from the database this info so it can load an image from the server because it knows the location. The problem is, I want to add two buttons for next and previous images. Right now I've got this:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id_image) AS currentpic, id_image, route FROM location.image
```

I create an index for the result of the select. I save and index on my javascript of the current picture show on the web, my idea is to send to the query a number and get the row that is the picture I want. If i use id_image for the index, i could have wrong result (cause id_image could store 4 and the next value could be 6, as you can see up there). If I do this

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id_image) AS currentpic, id_image, route FROM location.image WHERE currentpic = 3
```

I've got an error of column not found

Comment: "I've got an error of column not found". What is the *exact*, *copied and pasted* text of that error? It specifies which column in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must access the value in the outer query, just like the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html) says.

```
SELECT currentpic,
       id_image,
       route
FROM   (SELECT Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id_image) AS currentpic,
               id_image,
               route
        FROM   location.image) AS q
WHERE  currentpic = 3
```

Comment: Thanks! it did work! Sorry, I didn't see that part of the manual :(.